# Is there an early 90s DC series or tales about a race of aliens that could transform and give others powers accidentally?

Tags: dc, comics, superman, episode-identification

After the **Death of Superman** in 1992, comics changed, and DC got a *lot* of stories out of it. Subsequent to Superman's demise, 4 new "Supermen" appeared to take his place; one was John Henry Irons (basically a hybrid of Tony Stark and Michael Jordan) who donned an advanced armor and red cape to protect people as Superman had saved him, being known as the *Man of *Steel.** He was the main hero of that *Superman* title until Clark's return a year and half later.

In one MOS book, I remember that Irons had to fight a female alien that could change from a giant reptilian/xenomorph form to a red-clad human female. I bought the books as a kid, and there were a few details that seemed to point to it being an "arc" of sorts. What I remember:

- She survived by attacking humans and pulling out their spinal fluid with a type of proboscis.
- We saw her arrive with 4 or 5 other aliens similar to her of different colors, all of whom could shift to a human form.
- The human she attacked in the book was a friend of Irons, a young trainer who mutated to be able to generate spiked organic metal protrusions from his body.
- The alien survived and fled after being defeated by Steel and the trainer, protecting the young man's kid brother.

Does anyone know **who or what this alien race is** and whether there is a **story arc** about them?

Comment: The part about draining human spinal fluid sounds oddly familiar. I'll see what I can find, but I expect someone else will have answered this by them.

Comment: @F1Krazy I know, but its over 25 years old and kinda obscure. Anything you can find would be appreciated, friend.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're referring to the [Bloodlines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloodlines_(comics)) crossover event.

> "Bloodlines" was a 1993 comic book story arc published by DC Comics. It was an intracompany crossover that ran through DC's superhero annuals and concluded with a two-issue Bloodbath miniseries written by Dan Raspler. The antagonists were a race of monstrous xenomorph-like aliens who killed humans for their spinal fluid. A small fraction of the parasite's victims survived and become super-heroes via their ordeal. This plot device introduced a wave of "New Blood" superheroes into the DC Universe. Seven DC Comics series were spun out of the event: Blood Pack, Razorsharp and the Psyba-Rats, Hitman, Anima, Loose Cannon, Argus and Gunfire.

Truthfully, it largely fizzled, although *[Hitman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hitman_(DC_Comics))* had his own independent series, and *[Blood Pack](http://dcuguide.com/w/Blood_Pack)* had a team series.

I was familiar with it due to having looking up the background to *Hitman* when I read that series.

Comment: Ah, that's why it sounded familiar; I've looked up *Hitman* in the past as well. I went looking for an association with Steel and couldn't find one.

Comment: sounds like it; I remember the youth's brother calling him "edge". I figured it had to be the beginning of a Cross over of some kind. Thanks.